# Can I use api calls on someone else's sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am writing some code to access someone Google Sheets and look for a keyword, if that keyword is present I want to grab another column. Is this possible? Or do I have to use my own Google Sheet?

Comment: From `I am writing some code to access someone Google Sheets and look for a keyword`, I think that when you provide your current script, it might help users think of the solution about `if that keyword is present I want to grab another column.`. And also, the tag related to the language you are using can be known. By this, it will easy to see your question by users.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access spreadsheet owned by you or shared with you explicitly or indirectly (through a group, shared with anyone with the link, shared publicly)